# VHDL: Division and decimal representation

Tags: vhdl, fpga

The sensor that I'm using will return 16-bit word and convert it to an actual value I need to use an expression,

The expression is `((175.72*16b_word)/65536)-46.85.`

Can I divide by right shifting 16 positions?

I have searched for a couple of hours now and I still have no clue how to do with decimal representation! Does anyone have an example of how to solve it out?

Comment: NB not my DV, but please show your code. you are using fixed point representation, which is not common in VHDL, so you need to be specific.

Comment: Instead of using fixed point, shift all values so they are integers. make you calculations without removing information so if you have a software reading it can read to full value and convert it there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, shifting a binary number by 16 positions to the right is the same as a division by 65536 (with poor rounding however if your drop the shifted digits).